# Usando Provider no Context do ReactJs

Tags: javascript, react

Estou tentando usar o Context do ReactJs porém não consigo que a o Provider atribua o valor a variável de contexto.
sempre que verifico a variável vazia.

Context:

```
import React from 'react'
const AppContext = React.createContext({
  userData:{}
})
export default AppContext
```

Local onde passo a variável(exite valor nela)

```
console.log("USUARIO", user)
    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={{ userData: user }}>
```

Onde utilizo o Consumer:

```
 <AppContext.Consumer>
            {context => (
```

Comment: Olá Jason, no console log antes do return, o user está preenchido? Onde vc disse que está verificando a variável?

Comment: está sim, verifiquei isso.

Answer (score 0):

eu usei esse Context API só uma vez. Eu fiz assim:

No meu App.js eu instanciava o contexto assim

```js
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  loading: false,
  login: localStorage.getItem("tork") ? true : false,
  error: ""
};

export const AppContext = React.createContext(INITIAL_STATE);
```

e para passar o contexto para os componentes eu fazia assim:

```js
render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        <Routes signOut={() => this.signOut()} signIn={e => this.signIn(e)} />
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
```

**Sei que é basicamente igual ao seu, mas veja se dessa forma aí funciona.**